# ROS Package to filter raw IMU data (Linear Acceleration/Angular Velocity/Magnetic Orientation)

Tags: ros, imu, filter, kalman, data

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm going through the ROS packages for a generic package that will take raw IMU 9DOF readings and perhaps use a Kalman filter to fuse data from the Accelerometer, Gyroscope, and Magnometer. So far I've only found the [imu_filter_madgwick](http://wiki.ros.org/imu_filter_madgwick) package. However, it has been difficult to install with catkin. As a newbie to the ROS system I found this surprising.

**Is there a generic solution for IMU filtering in ROS?**

Thank you in advance. I would appreciate any guidance in this matter.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194766/ros-package-to-filter-raw-imu-data-(linear-acceleration/angular-velocity/magnetic-orientation)/) by [alainh](https://answers.ros.org/users/20406/alainh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2014-10-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you using the hydro branch? It works fine with catkin.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2014-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alainh](https://answers.ros.org/users/20406/alainh/) on 2014-10-11**:
You're absolutely right. I forgot to switch branches. Thank you! To continue the discussion, however, is this the only raw data IMU solution?

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2014-10-11**:
[robot_localization](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization) uses the IMU data in an EKF.

**Comment by [alainh](https://answers.ros.org/users/20406/alainh/) on 2014-10-24**:
Follow up: While I got most of the package dependencies to build, it trips up on the boost library from tf with errors. I made a separate question found here: http://answers.ros.org/question/194856/error-with-boost-while-building-tf-package-in-catkin-ws/